# Can I have generic constrain of type procedure of object in Delphi

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe4

Can I have a 'Generic constrain' of type 'procedure of object' in 'Delphi'.
I have given a piece of code to understand my issue.

```
var
  abc : procedure of object

  harry <T : abc > = class
  public
     procedure b (const handler : X);
  end;


procedure harry.b (const handler : X);
begin
  // do something
end;
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Delphi Generic constraints are not that flexible.  The documentation is very clear on what you can use as a constraint:

[Constraints in Generics](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Constraints_in_Generics):

> Constraint items include: 
>    Zero, one, or multiple **interface types** 
>    Zero or one **class type** 
>    **The reserved word "constructor", "class", or "record"**

A `procedure of object` does not satisfy any of those options.

Comment: Is there any way to implement this type of functionality.I mean to know if I can achieve this by some way or other.

Comment: No, there is not.  On the other hand, your example is not actually using the Generic parameter at all.  Had you done that, and you tried to pass something other than a `procedure of object`, then `b` would likely not compile when it tried to use `handler`.